# How to load data into multiple arrays in D3

Tags: arrays, d3.js

I have created a choropleth map based on this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606). It works fine, however I would now like to add buttons to toggle between different values in my tsv data: "rate" and "total"

```
id  rate    total
Macedonia   32.7    671000000
Turkey  22.8    10560000000
```

I think I need two datasets so that I can use buttons to toggle between them

```
rate = [{"id":"Estonia","rate":"6.6","id":"Latvia","rate":"13.7"}]
total =[{"id":"Estonia","total":"457000000","id":"Latvia","total":"286000000"}]

....

<button class="opts" value="rate">Rate</button>
<button class="opts" value="total">Total</button>

d3.selectAll('.opts')
  .on('click', function() {
    var data = eval(d3.select(this).property('value'));
    updateLegend(data);
  })
```

Im using d3.queue to load my data. How can I get my data into the correct structure? This is what I have so far

```
d3_queue.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "borders.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "data.tsv")
    .await(ready);    

function ready(error, rate, total) {    //This isn't working
   var rate = [{}];
   var total = [{}];

   data.forEach(function(d) {
    rate[d.id] = +d.rate;
    total[d.id] = d.total;

  });
```

[Full code here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ofFgECDYEPjokxn5EN7C?p=info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rate`and `total` variables you defined are arrays of objets, not objects. So you cannot write:

```
total[d.id] = d.total;
```

I think what you want to do is:

```
total.push({id: d.id, value: d.total});
```

One simple option might be to only the `data` structure, and to switch between between using `total`

Comment: Thank you! That fixes my arrays. However I seem broken my colours, do you know what I should be referencing here?     .enter().append("path").attr("class", function(d) { return quantize(d.id) }         https://plnkr.co/edit/ofFgECDYEPjokxn5EN7C?p=info

Comment: I didn't look at the full code before, because you're not directly binding `rate` and `total` directly using d3, it's actually best to use an object. Your code could look like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/gaXlgTuHxGL4zvBDSQkZ?p=preview

Also, because rate and totals have very different values, I think you should update `quantize.domain()` as part of `updateLegend`.